# How to get corporate SMIME certificates automatically into Mozilla Thunderbird?

Tags: active-directory, x509certificate, thunderbird, smime

If I use the corporate Outlook, I can choose to enrypt email messages without manually managing certificates.

In Thunderbird, I have to download and import a certificate for each recipient.

Is there a possibility to let Thunderbird download X.509 certificates (.cer files) from the same central place as Outlook does?

Comment: Most probably, Outlook gets the certificates from your company's LDAP (or Active Directory). You should be able to configure Thunderbird to use the same LDAP. [This may be helpful as a start.](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:Help_Documentation:Connecting_to_an_LDAP_address_book)